# How to click a specific button?

Tags: python

I am new to python. 
I am trying to make the game start, when the button `"pull"` is clicked.
But what I have, the game starts wherever I click in the `win`.

```
from graphics import*
from random import*
from time import*
def main():
    # Creating the window
    win = GraphWin("Clay Target Control Panel",400,400)

    # "Pull" rectangle and color
    pullrec = Rectangle(Point(150,290),Point(250,330))
    pullrec.setFill("light salmon")
    pullrec.draw(win)
    pullmess = Text(Point(200,310),"PULL")
    pullmess.setSize(11)
    pullmess.setStyle("bold")
    pullmess.draw(win)

    # Start the game when "Pull" rectangle is clicked.
    while True:
        mouse = win.getMouse()
        if pullrec:
            win.getMouse()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that win.getMouse blocks, waiting for a mouse click.  `pullrec` is bound to a rectangle.  `bool(<rectangle>)` is `True`, so `if rectangle` always fires.  You need to instead call some method that looks at where the mouse was clicked.  I know how to do this with `tkinter`, but not `graphics`.